# How to do multiple optional params with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using **"react": "^16.8.6"** and **"react-router": "^5.0.0"**

I am working on a search page.
And the page should have some filter condition
and the url look like this in regular way:
**/Search?SearchText=bachelor&State=New+South+Wales&CourseLevel=Diploma&CourseArea=Agriculture**

**how do I make it in react-router way?**

I was think about I can do it in this way, because the params is optional,
so the route could be
**/search/:CourseArea?/:State?/:CourseLevel?/:StudyMode?/:SearchText?**

but **how do I know which query is passed in url, and which not?**

Thank in Advance

Comment: Just pass object with these conditions as props instead of query parameters.

Comment: I'm working on something similar. I thougth that generatePath could save my day, but it doesn't work has i expected.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to parse the argument and leave your route just as is:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

class SearchComponent extends React.Component{
 render(){
  // url is 'https://www.example.com/search?id=123&type=4';
  let url = this.props.location.search;
  let params = queryString.parse(url);
  console.log(params);
  // The result will be like below
  // { id: 123, type: 4 }
  // other code
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution he's asking for. Even i'm trying to find answer to that.